# Strange problem installing a setup that I have just created

Tags: c#, installation

I have both VS 2005 and 2008 installed.

Just today I created a setup project in 2005 and I got this error when I tried to installed it.

"The folder path 'http://sharingcentre.info' contains an invalid character."

So I decided to create a simple project and added a new setup in 2005 and got the same problem.

I then converted the project to 2008 and added another new setup. The same problem happened again.

However, a previous setup project I created before work ok. I can install my application. Its only from today I cannot install any of my new setup projects. Using either 2005 and 2008.

Has anyone else had this same problem.

Searching google doesn't give me any real responses, I give the error message is too vague.

many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 0):

I removed the link that was in the setup property. That solved the problem.